# NFC Host Card Emulation for ubuntu mobile devices

Tags: nfc

does anyone know if NFC Host Card Emulation is supported on Ubuntu natively?  if not, we would like to supply the patch for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this is a question for https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/ or #ubuntu-touch on Freenode. You'll get a quicker response there (better use the mailing lists).